# symfony 3 file upload or download link in Form

Tags: symfony

I want to provide my users the possibility to upload their CVs / check and replace it in their profile's page.

Uploading the file works perfectly but I need to provide the download link instead of the file uploader in my user's profile form if the file has already been uploaded.

I wonder where/how to do it ?

I use doctrine to store my entities

```
 /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"application/pdf","application/x-pdf","text/pdf","text/x-pdf"})
     */
    private $cv;
```

and FormType linked to my entity to generate the profile's page form.

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
'data_class' => Worker::class));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array
$options)
{
    $builder->add('username')
              ...
             ->add('cv', FileType::class, array('label' => 'CV'))
```

Is using a FormEvent in the buildForm of the profile's Type to switch the type of field of "cv" in the builder a good option ? Or is there a better way to achieve this ?

in advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use [VichUploaderBundle on Symfony's site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html) or even look at that page for reference. I use it, and it's pretty easy to implement even on existing classes.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the bundle.
I followed the documentation to get the upload working. It does but my concern is by loading the entity back. I get an upload field where i would like a download link to retrieve the file attached to my entity.

Comment: I use this: `<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('{{ asset('documents/' ~ pet.getStudent.getBanId ~ '/' ~ att.document) }}')">View / Download</button>` on my system; where "att" is an attachment Entity. This is all using the VichUploaderBundle. I think this should work for you. If you can upvote my answer if you think I help, I would appreciate it. Let me know if you need further help.